# VS Xamarin Android SQLite-net crashing the app in Android v7.x

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make a cross platform app using Visual Studio 2015, Xamarin and SQLite. Everything is working fine until Android v6.0. But, when I test my app in android 7.x (7.0 and 7.1.1) emulators, my app crashed without even starting up. I read on xamarin forum about this crash under these links - [Link 1](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/) and [Link 2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/78234/android-libmonosgen-library-sqlite-problems-with-app-native-libraries) and came to know that since 7.0 native sqlite can't be used, but the answer there mentioned that -

> First I deleted the libraries from 'Manage NuGet Packages for
>   Solutions...' - library 'sqlite-net-pcl' and the connected one
>   'SQLitePCL.raw'. Then I installed the new version of through the
>   PackageManager Console, in my case the command was 'Install-Package
>   sqlite-net-pcl'. Now the versions are 'sqlite-net-pcl' --> 1.2.0 |
>   'SQLitePCL.raw' --> 1.0.1. Also it downloaded others dependencies like
>   SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green.

But, my project already has the updated version of sqlite-net-pcl and related packages.

```
sqlite-net-pcl => 1.2.0
SQLitePCL.bundle_green => 0.9.3
SQLitePCL.raw => 0.9.3
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green => 1.1.0
SQLitePCLRaw.core => 1.1.0
```

I am stuck here, they all are updated to the latest what should I change?

Relevant codes -

**SqliteService.cs**

```
using System;
using Medical_Study;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Medical_Study.Droid;
using System.IO;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SqliteService))]

namespace Medical_Study.Droid
{

    public class SqliteService : ISQLite
    {
        public SqliteService()
        {
        }

        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "QBank.db";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);

            // This is where we copy in the prepopulated database
            Console.WriteLine(path);

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var s = Forms.Context.Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.QBank);  // RESOURCE NAME ###

                // create a write stream
                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                // write to the stream
                ReadWriteStream(s, writeStream);
            }

            var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

            // Return the database connection 
            return conn;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// helper method to get the database out of /raw/ and into the user filesystem
        /// </summary>
        void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
        {
            int Length = 256;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            // write the required bytes
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }
            readStream.Close();
            writeStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**DataAccess.cs**

```
using System;
using SQLite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Medical_Study.Models;

namespace Medical_Study
{

    public class DataAccess
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        SQLiteConnection database;

        public DataAccess()
        {
            database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            // create the tables
            database.CreateTable<QBank>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<QBank> GetAllQuestions()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return (from i in database.Table<QBank>() select i).ToList();
            }

            //return database.Query<QBank>("Select * From [QBank] where [qid]");
        }

        public IEnumerable<QBank> GetSpecialQuestions()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return database.Query<QBank>("SELECT * FROM [QBank] WHERE [question_text] = 0");
            }
        }

        public QBank GetQuestion(int id)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return database.Table<QBank>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.qid == id);
            }
        }

        public int SaveQuestion(QBank question)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (question.qid != 0)
                {
                    database.Update(question);
                    return question.qid;
                }
                else
                {
                    return database.Insert(question);
                }
            }
        }

        public int DeleteQuestion(int id)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return database.Delete<QBank>(id);
            }
        }

    }

}
```